# I'm trying a beginner project to make like a login and register program with a txt file "serving as a database" in python

Tags: python

I want this: if the user inputs an email that already exists in the `.txt` file, the output should be that this email already exists there.

I don't want help with anything else, just this thing. And I'm aware that this is not finished, just got stuck here...

This is the code:

```py
choice=input("Choose if you want to register(1) or login(2): ")
if int(choice)==1:
    reg=input("Input your email: ")
    passreg1=input("Create your password: ")
    passreg2=input("Confirm your password: ")
    f=open("email.txt","r")
    lines=str(f.read())
    if reg==any(lines):
        print("You already have an account!")
    else:
        if str(passreg1)==str(passreg2):
            #f=open("email.txt", "a")
            #f.write("\n" + reg)
            #f.close()
            print("Account registered successfully.")
        else:
            print("Passwords do not match.")
else:
    log=input("Input your email: ")
    passlog=input("Input your password: ")
    print("Login successful!")
```

Also, in the text file I just have emails arranged like this:

> test@gmail.com
>
> hello@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `if reg == any(lines):`, to check if `reg` is in the list `lines`, we do: `if reg in lines:`

Comment: `lines` is not a list

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

```py
f=open("email.txt","r")
lines=str(f.read())
if reg==any(lines):
    print("You already have an account!")
```

by these:

```py
with open("email.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    if reg in lines:
        print("You already have an account!")
```

Comment: All above are necessary, as there was no f.close() in the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a txt with an email per line you can just read the file content as a string and then use the string *splitlines()* method to convert it as a list of lines. After that you can check if any entry of the list (a line) contains the email you are looking for:

```
lines=str(f.read().splitlines())
if reg in lines:
# ...
```